# Import into Android Studio with synchronized Git

Tags: git, import, android-studio

I'd like to take advantage of the new import in Android Studio to bring my very large Eclipse project over.  The main reason is to take advantage of the initial Gradle creation and add flavor support.

One of the big things that's changed is the file structure so that multiple flavors can be supported.  My eclipse project is already in git and I don't want to lose the history when the import automatically reorganizes the files.  Is there a way to get git to recognize the file "moves" during the import, or would every file have to be manually updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git is not tracking your files. Git is tracking the content of your files. The file name is just meta-data. Therefore git should be able to track your content even if the files are moved or renamed. Hence your history will not be lost.

EDIT

To provide you an example based on your comment I created a new git repository and added a new file. Git status shows the following:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   src/com/fun/HelloGitApp.java
#
```

After committing the new file I did run the following sequence of commands:

```
$ mkdir -p src/main/java/com/fun
$ mv src/com/fun/HelloGitApp.java src/main/java/com/fun/HelloGitApp.java
$ rm -R com/
$ git add --all
```

Git is now recognizing that the file was just renamed. You can test this with a new git status:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   renamed:    com/fun/HelloGitApp.java -> main/java/com/fun/HelloGitApp.java
#
```

Comment: I'm new to git (long time svn), so I assumed it would have no idea about moves that weren't commanded via the system.  So git should follow if I allow it to override an existing project directory with changes such as /src/com/fun/a.java to /src/main/java/com/fun/a.java

Comment: I edited my answer to provide you an example based on your comment. Hope this helps

Comment: I'm impressed that it was able to pick up that mv.  I'll go ahead and give the import a try and attempt an update in the fashion you showed.

Comment: Ok, the final status notes that all of the files are "new file", but also that they were "renamed" and shows the proper trace from old to new location.  Is it ok that existing files are showing up as "new file" and "renamed" in the same status?  Also can I checkout a clean copy from my local .git so I can confirm the modifications occurred correctly before I push?

Comment: Did you add all files? For example with git add --all . in the root of your repository? I don't know if you are aware of this fantastic free git book (http://gitscm.org/book). I believe it would be worth to read it.

Comment: As long as you do not push your repository to a remote repository, you are working locally. Other than with svn a commit is performed on your local repository. If you want to, you can clone your local repository to a new folder. Inside the target folder perform a git clone path_to_repository

Comment: That definitely seems to have done the trick.  I never woulda guessed git could keep up with the import changes, but at first glance it looks reliable.  Manual changes should be much more minor than I expected.  Boy I'm glad I decided to make the switch.  I'd be bald doing this in svn.  Thanks for helping me with what turned out to be a noob question! (BTW the book link is failing for me)